# iOS: Alternate way to return to app from Safari other than custom protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, afnetworking, dotnetopenauth

I am using `AFOAuth1Client` to authenticate with a provider (they use DotNetOpenAuth). Unfortunately the provider doesn't like a custom URL protocol such as `myapp://success` for the `callback` URL as it fails every time. If I use something like `http://www.mysite.com/success` it works correctly.

I need to direct the user back to my app, and because of this `callback` URL issue I am not sure what to do. Is there an alternate way, using standard protocols to redirect back to my app?

*Edit: I guess I could just create a redirect script on my website to then direct them to the custom protocol. But this isn't ideal.*

Comment: A dirty workaround:
Create a script on your server that sets the Location-header to myapp://success and pass the url to that script as callback url

Comment: I actually did that, which does work, but once I was returned to my app I get a "invalid signature" when trying to get the auth token. Not sure why.

Comment: Then you need to return all parameters returned by the OAuth provider to your app and parse everything in there accordingly.

Comment: I am doing that. I get the `oauth_verifier` and `oauth_token` back then redirect to my app and send them. But when using those to request the access token is where I get the error.